# JQM - data-dom-cache="true" on page not loading js files

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, dom, cordova

I got one strange behavior from JQM page.

I am using phonegap-android 4.4.2 with eclipse IDE.

Page code :

```
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <div data-role="page" id="folfirstForm" data-dom-cache="true">
            <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../../css/follow_up.css">
            <script src="../../js/addProdLine.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).off("pageshow", "#folfirstForm").on("pageshow", "#folfirstForm", function() {
                    alert("First form loaded!"); 

                    AddElement();
                });
            </script>
            ----Some body----
        </body>
</div>
  </div>
    </html>
```

You can see on code that I have put `data-dom-cache="true"` as per my requirement. I have also include the js file named as `addProdLine.js` which contains functions that i required, (for e.g. The `AddElement()` is from include file it self).

Now, when i am visiting this page first time all the functionality works very well. On second visit on same page I am getting the previous state of form which is expected as i have put `data-dom-cache="true"`. But Might be due to `data-dom-cache="true"` my external js files are not being loaded on the second time visit on same page. I want, that on every visit ,my js file should run.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery mobile only loads  tag once when whole document is loaded. After the document is loaded if you will click on other links then only content part `data-role=page` will be refreshed through ajax along with data transition effect. Hence either add all your js script in a file and add it into head tag or stop loading other pages through ajax using following option:

```
<a href="#" data-ajax=”false”>Without Ajax</a>
```

But if you will disable content loading using ajax then link will work as it works in normal webpage and also transition effect will be not exist.

**Edit:**

One Alternate way could be: you can append some random values to the path of your JS files.

```
<script src="../../js/addProdLine.js?Q=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: Okay, try alternate way in the answer. If you are not using php then you can use any method to generate random number in your scripting language.